# Octopus gem not working with active record relation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, octopus

Recently we thought of using slave databases for few of our search / read operations . We do not have any plans to send all our read request to slaves. We just want to few of our search queries to hit to slave databases

I tried almost all the available gems, `octopus, octoshark, db-charmer, makara, knockoff` , But none of them are working correctly.

`For example on Octopus (other gems too)`, below is a big issue

`Octopus.using(:slave1) do User.first end` .

This works fine and uses "slave1".

But not sure why the below is not working .

`Octopus.using(:slave1) do User.where(id: 1) end`

This one is not using slave1 but it fires on master database and most of our search queries are in this format.

It's quite frustrating till now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot struggle, I found that `User.where(id: 1)` just creates a active record relation, but the query gets executed outside of the `octopus`. So when I did `User.where(id: 1).to_a`, magically everything started working fine for me.

I tried with multiple most of them works with this trick. It took a lot of time for me to figure out.

Comment: Excellent diagnosis, Deepak. This is a surprising result.  I would think that yours is a very common scenario.  Looks like this is the same issue: https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus/issues/23 (I'm new to octopus, evaluating it for use)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try establishing the database connection directly in the `User` model?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  octopus_establish_connection(db_url_to_slave)
  ..
 end
```

We are currently using Octopus in production and I'm fairly certain the `where` use case works for us :P

This [section in the docs](https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus#mixing-octopus-with-the-rails-multiple-database-model) details the approach, in case you want more information.